# Jquery AJAX returns date object, second Call To Same function returns Date as String

Tags: jquery, ajax, date, format

I am experiencing weird behavior when calling a JQuery Ajax function a second time.  I isolated the call in a function, and just call the same function twice in a row.  I verified in Fiddler that BOTH the data sent to the server, and the data sent from the server are exactly the same in both AJAX calls.  Here is the AJAX request:

```
GetMeetingsList(myUserInfo);
GetMeetingsList(myUserInfo);

function GetMeetingList(myUserInfo) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/AM/GetMeetingList/" + myUserInfo.UserId + "/" + myUserInfo.CurrentAccountId + "/" + myUserInfo.DefaultGroupId + "/" + myUserInfo.AgendaDateRangeId + "/" + myUserInfo.key,
            type: "get",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (myReturn) {
                    DisplayMeetingsGrid(myReturn.myMeetingIEnumerable);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err.responseText);
            },
            complete: function () {
            }
        });
}
```

The server returns an Array of Meeting Objects.  One of the fields is a "MeetingDate" field of type DateTime on the server.  On the first call the client converts the date to a Date Object, on the second call the client converts the Date to a string even though the same exact data is being returned.  I used console.log to view the return data.

Here is the MeetingDate from the first call:

[image]

Here is the second call return MeetingDate:

[image: Second MeetingDate as String]

As you can see one is a date object and the other is a string.  Anyone know why?  My current solution for this is to loop through my meeting data and cast the string back to a date in the second call, which fixes my problem (solution below).  But I'd much rather not have to do this loop.

```
function DisplayMeetingsGrid(myMeetings) {

    $.each(myMeetings, function (key, value) {
        value.MeetingDate = new Date(value.MeetingDate);
    });
\\use the data
```

Comment: Is the raw server response the same from both requests as well?

Comment: Note that Date is not one of the JSON schema supported primitive type values: array, boolean, integer, number, string, object and null.  So the question is, what's parsing your string into a date upon fetching the Ajax request?

Comment: Steve - yes, both raw server responses are exactly the same (even the same character count) - verified in Fiddler, Raw view.  technophobia - yes that is the question, could it be a JQuery.Ajax bug possibly?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? jQuery uses [`jQuery.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to parse the response and return a JSON object accordingly.

Comment: Jquery version 2.1.1

Comment: I ran the string `'{"location":"Friendship", "MeetingDate" : "2015-06-09T00:00:00"}'` through `$.parseJSON()` as well as `JSON.parse()` and they both yield the expect results: i.e.: No string to date conversion.  That first response of yours is very strange.

Comment: @technophobia - yes, I originally thought my second return type was odd, but in fact it is the first response that is odd.  I ran a similar test where I dumbed down my object to just return the date without any other fields and the result was a string date as well.  So how does the first result get converted to a date object is unknown.